# Ruby-mode in Emacs in short-cut key for compile/run? 

Tags: ruby, emacs

I know a little bit about Emacs as I used it to write my thesis in AUCTex.

However, this time when trying to write some simple ruby program mostly to learn, I googled around for Ruby in Emacs and couldn't found what I am looking for.

Based on what I read so far, I know that the Emacs(23.3.5) I am using has in-build ruby-mode, which should support basically syntax highlighting, auto indenting etc. But how about short-cut key for debug/run, something like [Mode Compile](https://github.com/emacsmirror/mode-compile)?

Comment: I don't see a question here. Binding `mode-compile` to a key is done like any other key-binding in Emacs. `ruby-mode` is entered in every file with a `.rb` extension. It is documented like every other mode with `M-x describe-mode`. There is a bazillion of Emacs tutorials out there and accessible with your favorite search engine.

Comment: Please break this down into clear specific questions so they can be addressed individually.  What key do you think is missing?  What do you want to happen when you press this key?  What efforts have you made to resolve this on your own?  What has blocked you from doing so?

In other words, don't make people who try to help you do all the work.

Comment: @evernt_jr, I don't have much experience about Emacs, so I just don't know what ruby-mode do? Will it do compile/run using 'ruby -w my_program.rb' if so, how?

Comment: @pmr, I did mention that I googled, and I did search ruby-mode tutorial, emacs ruby tutorial etc, and then come back to ask the question. Basically I just ask for a pointer, like 'M- describe-mode'. Because I found in ruby-mode, doesn't looks like it there is a short-cut key for compile/run, did I missed a function from ruby-mode or there is something else, if there is a function from ruby-mode I missed, how do I found out what ruby-mode can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [quickrun.el](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-quickrun) which is maintenanced by me.

quickrun.el is a extension to execute editing buffer.
quickrun.el supports many programming languages and markup languages, of course
it supports Ruby.

You download quickrun.el following URL.

https://raw.github.com/syohex/emacs-quickrun/master/quickrun.el

And you add quickrun.el following setting to your configuration file and evaluate it(or restart Emacs).

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp") ;; If you install quickrun.el to ~/.emacs.d/elisp
(require 'quickrun)
```

Now you can use following command to execute current buffer.

```
M-x quickrun
```

You can use compile current buffer(not execute).

```
M-x quickrun-compile-only
```

If you will often use quickrun command, you should assign key bindings, like following.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'quickrun)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'quickrun-compile-only)
```

Please see [github page](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-quickrun), if you know more information about quickrun.el.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I am using quickrun now. I consider it is better for my usage as it is relative simple to install/config and to use as well. And it works as I would expected: compile/run after I input my command without any extra steps to see the result.

Comment: Thanks for an awesome package syohex!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `inf-ruby` to get an IRB session inside Emacs. Then you can use e.g. <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> to call `inf-ruby-load-file` to load your buffer inside the IRB session.

Additionally you might also want to use [Flymake](http://flymake.sourceforge.net/) to constantly syntax check your buffer against `ruby -c`. Here are 3 functions I took from the [emacs-starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit):

```
(defun flymake-ruby-init ()
  (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                     'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
         (local-file (file-relative-name
                      temp-file
                      (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
    ;; Invoke ruby with '-c' to get syntax checking
    (list "ruby" (list "-c" local-file))))

(defun flymake-ruby-enable ()
  (when (and buffer-file-name
             (file-writable-p
              (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))
             (file-writable-p buffer-file-name)
             (if (fboundp 'tramp-list-remote-buffers)
                 (not (subsetp
                       (list (current-buffer))
                       (tramp-list-remote-buffers)))
               t))
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c d")
                   'flymake-display-err-menu-for-current-line)
    (flymake-mode t)))

(eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
  '(progn
     (require 'flymake)
     (push '(".+\\.rb$" flymake-ruby-init) flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)
     (push '("Rakefile$" flymake-ruby-init) flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)
     (push '("^\\(.*\\):\\([0-9]+\\): \\(.*\\)$" 1 2 nil 3)
           flymake-err-line-patterns)
     (add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'flymake-ruby-enable)))
```

Additionally I use the following function for displaying the Flymake errors at point:

```
;; Flymake errors at point from Dave Love on gnu.emacs.help:
(defun my-flymake-show-help ()
   (when (get-char-property (point) 'flymake-overlay)
     (let ((help (get-char-property (point) 'help-echo)))
       (if help (message "%s" help)))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-flymake-show-help)
```

All of the above together make for a very decent Ruby Emacs experience.

Comment: I am trying to get inf-ruby working. I just discovered ELPA and installed inf-ruby thought that, do I still need do that         :;; If you're installing manually, you'll need to:
;; * drop the file somewhere on your load path (perhaps ~/.emacs.d)
;; * Add the following lines to your .emacs file:
;;    (autoload 'inf-ruby "inf-ruby" "Run an inferior Ruby process" t)
;;    (autoload 'inf-ruby-keys "inf-ruby" "" t)
;;    (eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
;;      '(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'inf-ruby-keys))
Otherwise seems I need using 'C-c C-s' to load inf-ruby first in order to 'C-c C-l'

Comment: It should be in your load path, just play around a bit in a scratch buffer and look at `ruby-mode-hook` etc to see if you still need to set something.

Comment: Also will IRB performance as good/slow as Ruby in shell or slower?

Comment: Installed inf-ruby, and I am still testing it out. Seems strange that after 'inf-ruby-load-file', I have to do 'ruby-switch-to-inf' to able to see the irb result?

Answer (score 0):

You can run ruby program from <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile` and get use "ruby -w your_program".

The output will be similar to compilation output, so you can click on errors to go to the line.

It looks like mode-compile also supports ruby-mode.

Comment: F12 will even working better than 'M-x compile', but I am looking for something function like mode-compile. The problem with mode-compile is it seems out of maintenance.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that F12 is the shortcut key defined by myself. But still my point is that I want be able to run/compile my program without the need to type filename, I know that with 'M-x compile' it is actually not that bad as it will auto complete most of the time. I am ask the questions mostly to consider my options and see what others are using, so thank you for your input. It is indeed a valid point. And I can see the simplicity of this approach.